# same code working for other API but not for this API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

The same code working for another API but not for this API

Let me know if I am missing something. I'm not able to fix this issue and get this below error message

`items.map is not a function`

```
import React from "react";

class Statelist extends React.Component {
  // Constructor
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items: [],
      DataisLoaded: false
    };  
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const apiUrl = "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=tesla&from=2023-04-10&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=ad1b44319c0d4252ab7dcbfb0b2a4d9c";

    fetch(apiUrl)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        this.setState({
          items: json,
          DataisLoaded: true
        });
      })
  }

  render() {
    const { DataisLoaded, items } = this.state;
    if (!DataisLoaded) return
      <div>
        <h1>Pleses wait some time....</h1>
      </div>;

    return (
      {items.map((item) => (
        <tr>
          <td>{item.id}</td>
          <td>{item.articles[0].author}</td> 
          <td>{item.name}</td>
          <td>{item.email}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    );
  }
}

export default Statelist;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Nobody can tell you what's wrong with code we can't see.  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Having said that... If the error is telling you that `items.map` is not a function then `items` is not an array.  `.map()` is a function on arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> items.map is not a function

Then `items` is not an array.  So what is it?

It's *initialized* as an array here:

```
this.state = {
  items: [],
  DataisLoaded: false
};
```

But later is updated here:

```
this.setState({
  items: json,
  DataisLoaded: true
});
```

Which means `json` is not an array.  So what is it?

Visiting the API URL in your code, I see data starting with:

```
{"status":"ok","totalResults":13394,"articles":[
```

(and so on)

Well, that's not an array.  It's an object.  Perhaps you want that top-level `articles` property on the object, which contains an array?:

```
this.setState({
  items: json.articles,
  DataisLoaded: true
});
```

I can't know for certain, but you can.  You can examine the structure of the data you're receiving from the API and decide what data you want from that structure and how you want to use that data.

As far as *the error itself* is concerned, you simply can't call `.map()` on an object, only on an array.

Comment: did that but getting this 
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Comment: <code>
this.setState({
     items: json.articles,
     DataisLoaded: true
    });
    <code>

Comment: @SarmisthaDas: If `item.articles[0]` is producing the error in that comment then clearly `item.articles` is `undefined`.  What do you expect that value to be and why?  Both the original error and this new error imply that you're mostly just *guessing* what data you have, rather than actually observing.  You need to observe your data, understand its structure, and use that structure.

Comment: understand, thanks you :-) 
its working now !!